# Is there any Java decompiler GUI

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, java

I am using Eclipse, and just lost some important .java files from Ubuntu 14.04. Now I am left out with just .class files. I know about Java Decompiler, but jd-eclipse is not working. I need a Java decompiler for recovering my files or is there any other way to recover deleted files (not like extundelete) to recover my .java files?

If not, is there any easy way to use Java Decompiler?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/272535/1531971 Many of those are pure Java, and will work just fine on any platform that has a semi-official JVM. Be aware that there are some classes may not be able to fully recover, and certainly you will not get back your identical source.

Answer (score 1):

Try [JReversePro](http://jreversepro.blogspot.com)

There are other command line compilers out there too - just Google.